# docker secrets and refresh tokens

Tags: docker, token, docker-secrets

I'm looking for a way to use docker secrets and for all case where I don't need to update the stored value of the secret that would be a perfect situation but my app is having multiple services which are having 3 legged OAuth authorization. After successfully obtaining all tokens a script is collecting all tokens then creating secrets out of them and executing the config of my docker.compose.yml file with the container using those secrets. The problem is when the tokens have to be refreshed and stored again as secrets. Docker secrets does not allow updating the secrets. What would be the possible workaround or better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not update a secret or config in place. They are immutable. Instead, include a version number in your secret name. When you need to change the secret, create a new one with a new name, and then update your service with the new secret version. This will trigger a rolling update of your service.